# Find all functions over naturals that they hold an equality

Tags: functions

The task itself is not that hard i'd say.
I have to find all functions $f: \mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$ that equality $f(\pi(n)) = \pi(f(n))$ is true.
Where $\pi(n)$ stands for ANY permutation over the naturals.

My idea is that, if $f(\pi(n))$ gives some number X, then if we want $\pi(f(n))$ to give same number, then $f(n)$ must be an inversion of our permutation, it is $\pi^{-1}(n)$. And i have checked this on few examples and it turnes out to be true.

And my conclusion is that there is no such function, because one function can not be inversion for more than one permutation.

And my question is: how to show that more mathematically correctly ( of course if only it's good solution )? Thanks for any effort from you ;-)

Comment: Well, there's one obvious function which satisfies this.

Comment: What about $\;f(n)=0\;$ , **if** for you $\;0\in\Bbb N\;$ ?

Comment: Antonio, no, zero doesnt belong to naturals in this case.

Comment: There is at least one such function: if $f(n)=n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, then $f\big(\pi(n)\big)=\pi(n)=\pi\big(f(n)\big)$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$ and permutation $\pi$ of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: If $0$ is not a natural number, then what is $\pi(1)$?

Comment: Oh, right. I just missed the identity function. That's embarassing. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio this does not seem to help: not all permutations satisfy $\pi(0)=0$.

Comment: Permutation is some bijection from $N$ to $N$ right? So, does zero really matter? 

Thanks Andrew for new idea about it.

Comment: But i don't know if we can say that $f(n)$ can be any power of $\pi(n)$, cause $f(n)$ is somehow fixed and we want to test it with all permutations. So is it true if we say that $f(n) = \pi(n)$? It makes $f(n)$ pretty dynamic, not static, at least to my understanding of this. Am i right or false?

Comment: Do you want to find all $f$ that satisfy $f\circ \pi=\pi\circ f$ for all permutations $\pi$? Or for a given $\pi$, find all $f$ such that $f\circ \pi=\pi\circ f$?

Comment: @Hagen: As I read the question, it’s the former.

Comment: Oh, duh, I should read the question. Of course. I was reading $\pi$ as the prime counting function. Never mind. Will delete my comments.

Comment: No problem man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But there is at least one such function: if $f(n)=n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, then $f\big(\pi(n)\big)=\pi(n)=\pi\big(f(n)\big)$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$ and permutation $\pi$ of $\Bbb N$. The identity map is, however, the only such function.

Suppose that $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is not the identity function; then there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(n)\ne n$. Let $m=f(n)$, and let $k=f(m)$. If $k\ne n$, let $\pi$ be the permutation of $\Bbb N$ that interchanges $m$ and $n$; then $$f\big(\pi(n)\big)=f(m)=k\ne n=\pi(m)=\pi\big(f(n)\big)\;,$$ and $f$ does not have the desired property. If $k=n$, then $k\ne m$; let $\ell\in\Bbb N\setminus\{m,n\}$, and let $\pi$ be the permutation of $\Bbb N$ that interchanges $m$ and $\ell$; then

$$f\big(\pi(n)\big)=f(n)=m\ne\ell=\pi(m)=\pi\big(f(n)\big)\;,$$

and again $f$ does not have the desired property.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice and clear answer! I need to work more on those formal proofs ;)

Comment: @Chris: You’re welcome!